# Xcode "Class ... is implemented in both ... . One of the two will be used"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have created a custom Framework. The Framework has some SwiftPM dependencies like Alamofire that it makes use of.

If I add the Framework to my app, I can't build the app without adding the dependencies to my app as well. After doing that and running the app, I can even remove the Frameworks from the app's SwiftPM dependencies and it's working fine but only until I clear the build folder.

Having the dependency in both the app and the Framework I get dozens of prints that say

```
objc[13048]: Class _TtC11CryptoSwift3AES is implemented in both 
/Users/Z/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F0/MyApp.app/Frameworks/MyKit.framework/MyKit (0x106c8e960) and 
/Users/Z/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F0/MyApp.app/MyApp (0x1052ccd20). 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

After cleaning the build folder it again tells me `Missing required module 'Alamofire'`.

How can I make either the Framework happy with the dependencies from the app or the app happy with the dependencies from the Framework? The app doesn't access Alamofire directly, only the Framework does.

So I'd like to either build the Framework without including the dependencies to it or build the app without including the dependencies to it which will hopefully resolve this warning.